# Arduino чтение пакета известной длины по Serial порту

Tags: arduino, serial, byte

Устройство принимает по Serial API-пакеты известной длины (25 байт) Необходимо записать весь пакет в байтовый массив buf_command[25] для дальнейшего анализа, пробовал так

```
while(Serial.available())
{
    byte inBuf = Serial.read();     //прочитать байт по последовательному порту
    Serial.println();
      if (i_byte<25){           //если байт не последний 25-й
          buf_command[i_byte] = inBuf;   //добавить полученный байт в массив 
          i_byte++;
      }
      else {                              //иначе
            i_byte = 0;                  //обнулить счетчик                
              }
           }
```

Но получалась какая то чепуха (в весь массив нормально записался только первый байт)
Как сделать, чтобы весь разовый пакет поместился в массив??

Comment: Вы учитываете, что пакет не обязан приходить за один раз?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал сделать так:

```
for (char n = 0; n < 25; ++n)
{
   while( ! Serial.available()) ; // Ждём, данные получим
   buf_command[n] = Serial.read();
}
```